Is there a way to import ERC4337 smart wallet to another app or extract its private key?
I was using Obvious! ERC4337 smart wallet for several months without any issue. Recently there is a problem on my app I can't send or sign any swaps using their app on my smartphone. Not sure if it is a connection problem from my side or my app just lagging.
I have the seed phrase but it is useless when inserted into any other wallet app as I far as I understand those smart wallets are like a special smart contract.
Is there a way to find the private key or import that smart wallet to any other app compatible with ERC4337?
Can Iancoleman BIP39 offline tool help me extract the private key of the ERC4337 smart wallet from the seed phrase or it doesn't work that way?
